# Como esconder o scrollbar

Tags: css, rolamento, html

Como esconder o `ScrollBar` com o *CSS*? Não estou conseguindo.

Já tentei em vários editores, porém não consigo. O que eu faço?

Comment: É sempre bom incluir na pergunta o código que vc tem tentado fazer e que não está funcionando, e incluir mais detalhes para maior clareza. Por exemplo: vc não especificou qual scrollbar quer esconder (existem 2).

Answer (score 1):

Se for a scrollbar da viewport faz assim com o CSS:

```
body{
overflow: hidden;
}
```

para um elemento HTML:

```
elemento, .classe, #id {
overflow: hidden;
}

/* BARRA HORIZONTAL */
body{
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

para um elemento HTML:

```
elemento, .classe, #id {
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.suaClasse{
overflow: hidden;
}

Answer (score -1):

```
overflow-y: hidden
```

ou

```
overflow-x: hidden
```